# Usar PDO en PHP para Conectar con la base de datos SQL Sever

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, ssms

Intento conectarme a la base de datos de Microsoft SQL Server Managament Studio con PDO pero me dice que ha ocurrido un error al conectar a la base de datos. Aqui adjunto el codigo:

```
private $conn;

function __construct() {        
} 
/**
 * Establishing database connection
 * @return database connection handler
 */
function connect() {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . './Config.php';

    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        // returing connection resource
        return $this->conn;

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {

        // if the environment is development, show error details, otherwise show generic message
        if ( (defined('ENVIRONMENT')) && (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') ) {
            echo 'An error occured connecting to the database! Details: ' . $ex->getMessage();
        } else {
            echo 'An error occured connecting to the database!';
        }
        exit;
    }

}
```

Comment: que exception te arroja el sistema cuando se va por el catch?

Comment: @JoseReynel 'An error occured connecting to the database!'

Comment: concatenale al string que tienes los siguiente $ex->getMessage(), de esta forma vamos a poder ver de que error se trata...

Comment: me dice esto: could not find driver

Comment: en ese caso mira porfa la siguiente URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852748/pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: pero ese no seria el caso para mysql?

Comment: revisa tu archivo php.ini y mira las directivas de pdo para sqlserver que se encuentren sin ";" de esa forma van a quedar habilitadas y luego reinicias apache para que tu server tome el cambio.

Comment: @JoseReynel ya lo habilite y reinicie apache, todavía nada

Comment: Hola Rosibel buen día, si sigue el mismo error...revisa porfa con el example que te adjunto en la rpta para ver si el error persiste, crea un script aparte para ver si tmb te genera la inconsistencia y prueba ese script en otro pc con una instalación diferente de php y así sabes si es algo del server o es algo relacionado a tu código fuente... saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con la finalidad de orientar frente a como realizar la cx de t-sql con pdo en php a continuacion adjunto codigo fuente relacionado y la URL respectiva donde puedes validar tmb las directrices que deben estar habilitadas en el archivo php.ini:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'dblib:host=<ip address>;dbname=<database name>';
$user = 'user id';
$password = 'password';

try
{
    $pdo_object = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = "SELECT * from <some table>";
$pdo_statement_object = $pdo_object->prepare($sql);
$pdo_statement_object->execute();
// $result = $pdo_statement_object->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $pdo_statement_object->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Bibliografia: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.